# Unit testing a method whose statements run on different task

Tags: c#, multithreading, unit-testing, moq

I have a method:

```
public class WorkerClass : IWorkerClass
{
private int myworkId = 0;
public void Workflow(int theWorkid)
        {
            var aTask = new Task(() =>
            {
                this.myworkId = theWorkid;
                //Some calculations
              
            });

            aTask.Start();
        }
}
```

I have a Unit test method :

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow(23)]
public class workerTester
{
 public void WorkflowTest(int theWorkflowMode)
        {
            // Arrange 
           
            var aWorkTester = new Mock<IWorkerClass>();
            var aExpectedWorkflowMode = 23;
            myWorkerPrivateObj = new PrivateObject(aWorkTester);

            // Act

            myWorkerPrivateObj .Invoke("Workflow", theWorkflowMode);

            // Assert

            //Thread.Sleep(1000); If i uncomment it works
            var aActualWorkflowModeType = myWorkerPrivateObj.GetField("myworkId");
            Assert.AreEqual(aExpectedWorkflowModeType, aActualWorkflowModeType);
            
        }
}
```

If i uncomment Thread.Sleep(1000), aActualWorkflowModeType comes as 23. But if i comment it aActualWorkflowModeType comes as 0. I am assuming my assert is called before my task is complete.
How can i wait until task is complete in my Unit test?

Comment: You can't. Your method isn't returning a task that your test can wait for. Are you sure your method shouldn't be returning the task it created? It would make a lot more sense and be a lot easier to test.

Comment: Your method also doesn't make much sense, as it updates the state of the object from within the task. The current design allows you to call the method twice, with different id's, but the last one wins. I would redesign that class so that it wouldn't have any of the issues it now has.

Comment: [Don't use the `Task` constructors](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out a way to do it for unit testing:

```
     var lookupTask = Task<WorkerClass>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    return new WorkerClass();
                });
    
                lookupTask.Wait();
```

So my new Unit test method looks like this :

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow(23)]
public class workerTester
{
 public void WorkflowTest(int theWorkflowMode)
        {
            // Arrange 
           
            var aWorkTester = new Mock<IWorkerClass>();
            var aExpectedWorkflowMode = 23;
            myWorkerPrivateObj = new PrivateObject(aWorkTester);

            // Act

            myWorkerPrivateObj .Invoke("Workflow", theWorkflowMode);
            var lookupTask = Task<WorkerClass>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    return new WorkerClass();
                });

            // Assert
            lookupTask.Wait();
            var aActualWorkflowModeType = myWorkerPrivateObj.GetField("myworkId");
            Assert.AreEqual(aExpectedWorkflowModeType, aActualWorkflowModeType);
            
        }
}
```

This seems to work

Comment: That doesn't seem to be testing anything. You also seem to be using a mock to get `WorkerClass` and you're newing up one too. What are you testing?